# Python Django, API Call with user input

Tags: django

I’m currently building a little Django Project and I’ve got a question. I would like to make an API Call to an external API with a user input. How can I achieve that? Pretty new to Django sorry.

Regards,

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: It’s not a specific problem unfortunately, I really don’t know where to begin.

Answer (score 1):

You can make an API view in Django to receive the request from the user whos using your system with parameters from request body or header (user input) using `API View` following this link: [Django API View](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/views/#api_view).

You can implicitly take these params from the user and send them to the other system to make an API request using `requests` in python
for example: [Pyhton requests](https://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/#more-complicated-post-requests)